# Personalize colors ina distribution graphic ggplot 2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to personalize the colors in one density plot in ggplot2.

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(cond = factor(rep(c("A","B", "C"), each=300)), 
                  rating = c(rnorm(300, mean=1),rnorm(300, mean=-1),rnorm(300, mean=0)))
library(plyr)
cdat <- ddply(dat, "cond", summarise, mean=mean(rating))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=rating, fill=cond)) +
  geom_density(alpha=.3) +
  geom_vline(data=cdat, aes(xintercept=mean,  colour=cond),
             linetype="dashed", size=1)
```

[image]
As you can observe in code, the usual field in which it’s useful in this function us used to order ggplot to separate by grupos the distributions.
how can I get to personalize the colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the line `scale_fill_manual() +` with the `values=` option:

For example:

```
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Red", "Yellow", "Pink")) +
```

[image]

You can use any reasonable colour names or submit your own with RGB or Hex:

```
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#393FD1", "#FFFFFF", "05C4A9")) +
```